# Sort a ListObject by Columns

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I am working with `ListObject` objects in VBA. In particular I am creating a table dynamically (variable number of rows and columns, and variable column headers). I have the need to sort the table's **columns** in **ascending alphabetical order**.

For instance if I have the table:

[image: Unsorted Table]

I want it to be sorted like so,

[image: Sorted Table]

Is there any way to do this? I have tried to use the `Range.Sort` method but it seems that this is not allowed if the range is part of a `ListObject`.

I also tried to record a macro to find code, but found that when I right clicked the table to sort it, the selected range left the header out and I was not able to select the "Sort left to right" option...

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the sort method of the list object, [as described here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh273486(v=office.14).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work. It takes the name of a table (e.g. "Table1"), converts it to a range, sorts it, then reconverts it to a table with the same name:

```
Sub SortByCol(tableName As String)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim myTable As ListObject
    Dim myStyle As TableStyle
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    Set myTable = sh.ListObjects(tableName)
    Set myStyle = myTable.TableStyle

    Set myRange = myTable.Range
    myTable.Unlist
    On Error Resume Next
    myRange.Sort key1:=myRange.Rows(1), Orientation:=xlSortRows
    If Err.Number > 0 Then Debug.Print "Range couldn't be sorted"
    On Error GoTo 0
    sh.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, myRange, , xlYes).Name = tableName
    sh.ListObjects(tableName).TableStyle = myStyle
End Sub
```

On edit: I added a bit of error handling around the sort method call. Experiments showed that my original code didn't preserve the style (if the table didn't have the default style then the result was a weird blend of the default style and the original table style). I added coded to save and then restore the original table style, but I don't know much about table formatting and might have missed some subtleties. At the very least, it seems to preserve the style if it was chosen from Excel's built-in list of table styles.

Comment: This looks promising! I will try this when I have the chance. I would suggest adding an error handler to recreate the table should the `Sort` call fail. Also does this preserve the table's styling? Or does it switch it to the default?

Comment: @MichaelSPriz I tested it on a table that used the default settings, so I am not sure. It was mostly meant as proof-of concept rather than production-level code.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I decided to restructure my data so that I did not need to do this. But your code works and hopefully will be useful to whoever else has this problem.

Comment: Thanks -- though I can't help feeling that there must be a way to be able to sort by column-headers directly using the ListObject's sort method, though whenever I try I find that the presence of headers prevents me from changing the orientation of the sort. I'm thinking that I could do something like insert a new row whose values echo the headers -- sort by that row -- then delete the row, though I haven't been able to get it to work yet.